# How do I ignore tags while getting the .string of a Beautiful Soup element?

Tags: python, dom, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm working with HTML elements that have child tags, which I want to "ignore" or remove, so that the text is still there. Just now, if I try to `.string` any element with tags, all I get is `None`.

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""
    <div id="main">
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph <span class="test">with a tag</span>.</p>
      <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    </div>
""")

main = soup.find(id='main')
for child in main.children:
    print child.string
```

Output:

```
This is a paragraph.
None
This is another paragraph.
```

I want the second line to be `This is a paragraph with a tag.`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for child in soup.find(id='main'):
    if isinstance(child, bs4.Tag):
        print child.text
```

And, you'll get:

```
This is a paragraph.
This is a paragraph with a tag.
This is another paragraph.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.strings` iterable](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) instead. Use `''.join()` to pull in all strings and join them together:

```
print ''.join(main.strings)
```

Iterating over `.strings` yields each and every *contained* string, directly or in child tags.

Demo:

```
>>> print ''.join(main.strings)

This is a paragraph. 
This is a paragraph with a tag. 
This is another paragraph.
```