# How to make BeautifulSoup 'replace_with' attribute work with a 'unicode' object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my `html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Pizza</h2>
<p>This is some random paragraph without child tags.</p>
<p>Delicious homebaked pizza.<br><em></em>$8.99 pp</em></p>
<h2>Eggplant Parmesan</h2>
<p>Try the authentic <i>Italian flavor</i> of baked aubergine.<br><em>$6.99 pp</em></p>
<h2>Italian Ice Cream</h2>
<p>Our dessert specialty.<br><em>$3.99 pp</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Using BeautifulSoup, I want to grab the text that is displayed for the `h2` and `p` tags, replace them with a prefixed version in the tree, and also print them out on screen. For the `h2` tags, this works fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("/var/www/html/Test/index.html", "r") as f:
 soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

f = open("/var/www/html/Test/I18N_index.html", "w+")

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    i18n_string = "I18N_"+h2.string
    h2.string.replace_with(i18n_string)
    print(h2.string)

f.write(str(soup))


###Output:##############################################
# $ python ./test.py
# I18N_Pizza
# I18N_Eggplant Parmesan
# I18N_Italian Ice Cream
########################################################
```

In my I18N_index.html, all 3 strings appear correctly prefixed with 'I18N_'.

However, my `p` tags contain child tags, and for these the return type is 'None'. As a result, the concatenation no longer works:

```
    for p in soup.find_all('p'):
        i18n_string = "I18N_"+p.string
        p.string.replace_with(i18n_string)
        print(p.string)

    f.write(str(soup))

###Output:##################################################
# $ python ./test.py
# I18N_Pizza
# I18N_Eggplant Parmesan
# I18N_Italian Ice Cream
# I18N_This is some random paragraph without child tags.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
  # File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    # i18n_string = "I18N_"+p.string
# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
############################################################
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280506/how-do-i-ignore-tags-while-getting-the-string-of-a-beautiful-soup-element) I learned about the `join` function. It let's me do the concatenation and print out the resulting strings on screen, but not the replacement in the soup tree:

```
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    joined = ''.join(p.strings)
    i18n_string = "I18N_"+joined
    #joined.replace_with(i18n_string)
    print (i18n_string)

###Output with 'joined.replace_with(i18n_string)' DISABLED:###
# I18N_Pizza
# I18N_Eggplant Parmesan
# I18N_Italian Ice Cream
# I18N_This is some random paragraph without child tags.
# I18N_Delicious homebaked pizza.$8.99 pp
# I18N_Try the authentic Italian flavor of baked aubergine.$6.99 pp
# I18N_Our dessert specialty$3.99 pp
############################################################

###Output with 'joined.replace_with(i18n_string)' ENABLED:#####
# I18N_Pizza
# I18N_Eggplant Parmesan
# I18N_Italian Ice Cream
# Traceback (most recent call last):
  # File "./test.py", line 41, in <module>
    # joined.replace_with(i18n_string)
# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'replace_with'
############################################################
```

In that thread, another solution based on `isinstance` is mentioned, but I could not make that work.

If I understand correctly, the join function joins the strings but returns a 'unicode' object, not a string object, and this is why the 'replace_with' attribute doesn't work. How can I work around this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace_with()` method does not work not because `joined` is a unicode object, but because it is a method specific to bs4 object. See this: [BeautifulSoup-replace_with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)

By the way the `join()` method return a `str` See this: [python3-join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_join.htm)

Now to give you a solution, I would simply remove the `string` after the `p` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html", "r") as f:
 soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

f = open("I18N_index.html", "w+")

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    i18n_string = "I18N_"+h2.string
    h2.string.replace_with(i18n_string)
    print(h2.string)

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    joined = ''.join(p.strings)
    i18n_string = "I18N_"+joined
    p.replace_with(i18n_string)
    print (i18n_string)


f.write(str(soup))
```

*OUTPUT:*

`I18N_Pizza
I18N_Eggplant Parmesan
I18N_Italian Ice Cream
I18N_This is some random paragraph without child tags.
I18N_Delicious homebaked pizza.$8.99 pp
I18N_Try the authentic Italian flavor of baked aubergine.$6.99 pp
I18N_Our dessert specialty.$3.99 pp`

Comment: This solution works. Thanks a lot, also for the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

With a simplified version of your code (that is, just taking care of the `p` tags issue), it looks like you have to replace `p.string` with `p.text`:

soup = BeautifulSoup([your html], "lxml")

```
 for p in soup.find_all('p'):
   print('before: ',p.text)
   i18n_string = "I18N_"+p.text
   print('after ',i18n_string)
```

Output:

```
before:  This is some random paragraph without child tags.
after  I18N_This is some random paragraph without child tags.
before:  Delicious homebaked pizza.$8.99 pp
after  I18N_Delicious homebaked pizza.$8.99 pp
before:  Try the authentic Italian flavor of baked aubergine.$6.99 pp
after  I18N_Try the authentic Italian flavor of baked aubergine.$6.99 pp
before:  Our dessert specialty.$3.99 pp
after  I18N_Our dessert specialty.$3.99 pp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried 'text' before, but it did not resolve my inability to use 'replace_with'.